# overwrite setup function at testcase

Tags: delphi

Can I overwrite the setup and teardown functions of a TTestcase from a class helper function for this particular testcase ?

like

```
MytestCase =   class(TTestCase)
   //   here is my testcase 
end;

MyTestCaseEXT = class helper for  MytestCase
    ...
    procedure Setup ; override;
    ...
end;

MyTestCaseEXT.setup;
begin
    ///  do some special stuff at start
    .....
    ..
    ///   now do normal setup ....  if not fail at start up 
    if not fail(...) then
    inherited;   //
    else
    exit;
end;
```

optional approach

```
MyTestcaseHelper = class helper for MyTestCase
    ...
    protected
      procedure SetUp; override;
     procedure TearDown; override;
   published
     [TestCase( )]
     function Init( .....  ) : Boolean;
   end;
```

With above code skeleton I get a compiler error, methode setup not found in class, ERROR = E2137; as setup is not the class constructor is should be possible ....

This error also occurs when I try to overwrite the setup function from my derived MyTestcase within the class helper

Comment: Class helpers do not allow method overriding as far as I remember. But you might get luck with an interposed class.

Comment: Why don't you override the method in your subclass? Helpers allow you to add new methods, to extend the scope. They don't allow you to change existing methods.

Comment: @David : I have no success with this proposal, Iit would working IT could solve my problems

Comment: Overriding methods works